# Empty map after multiple using of Stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, java-8, java-stream

I'm creating two maps from different columns in csv (tab delimited)

```
oldVal1   newVal1   2
oldVal2   newVal1   3
oldVal3   newVal1   11
       .
       .
       .
```

and merge these together at the end. Let me provide just dirty implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream somefile = new FileInputStream("d:\\dummyfile.csv");

    Map<String, String> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> secondMap = new HashMap<>();

    Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(somefile, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)).lines();

    firstMap = streamSupplier.get()
            .map(p -> p.split("\t"))
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[1],
                            Collectors.mapping(g -> g[2],
                            Collectors.joining(","))));

    secondMap = streamSupplier.get().map(p -> p.split("\t"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0],
                    s -> s[2]));

    firstMap.putAll(secondMap);
}
```

The issue I'm facing with is the secondMap is empty.

Desired output is supposed to be

```
Map<String, String>:

oldVal1 -> 2
oldVal2 -> 3
oldVal3 -> 11
newVal1 -> 2,3,11
```

Is there anything I'm missing in the code or another way how to resolve this issue? Thanks for any of your help.

Comment: Personal quirk: I'd only read the file once. That said, how are you verifying the second map is empty? If the maps have overlapping keys, then you're overwriting the second map with the first

Comment: The keys in both maps are always different.

Comment: But how are you verifying that? Also, show some input data for the question's sake. As I see now, this code shouldn't compile (`Stream<String, String>`?)

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example with input and expected output please? It's hard to help with that little details

Comment: your code doesn't compile, does `Stream<String, String>` exists? I have several errors in the first collect as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> secondMap = streamSupplier.get().map(p -> p.split("\t"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[1],
         s -> s[2]));
```

When executing above code, buffereReader is empty so secondMap didn't fill as excepted.

Just read inputstream again, it will solve it. Or you can store it to memory.

```
InputStream somefile2 = new FileInputStream("deneme.txt");
streamSupplier = () -> new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(somefile2, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)).lines();
Map<String, String> secondMap = streamSupplier.get().map(p -> p.split("\t"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[1],
         s -> s[2]));
```

Comment: This won't solve an issue.I'm getting secondMap empty even if I read inputstream once again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing the same stream for each `Map`, you need to process separate streams as shown below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Read all lines
        List<String> linesList = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

        // First map
        Map<String, String> firstMap = 
                linesList
                .stream()
                .map(p -> p.split("\t"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[1], Collectors.mapping(g -> g[2], Collectors.joining(","))));
        System.out.println(firstMap);

        // Second map
        Map<String, String> secondMap = 
                linesList
                .stream()
                .map(p -> p.split("\t"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[2]));
        System.out.println(secondMap);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{newVal1=2,3,11}
{oldVal2=3, oldVal3=11, oldVal1=2}
```